# Is there a way to pass a query string or string value from one react app to another react app on button click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I have control of the two webapps. Both are both on Reactjs and nodejs. One is a booking webapp and the other is an affiliate app. Basically, you create a booking with a payment gateway on the booking app while the affiliate app simply promotes a package that uses the booking app for booking and payment.
I control both of them. As at now, I want to keep the booking app strictly booking. I want to add the package sales page on the affiliate app.
So, when a user who is an affiliate generates a custom link to promote a particular package, the link contains the url to that package plus a query string of that affiliate user's unique affiliate identifier. When you click on this link, it takes you to that package sales page which has `book now` button.
When you click the `book now` buttton, it takes you to the booking page.
Is there a way I can pass this affiliate unique identifier while redirecting the user to the booking page?
Remember, the booking page is a different website but I have control of both.
So, far, I am thinking if I could save the affiliate user identifier string along with the package unique string in the local storage of the visitor. When the visiting user successfully books that same package, I could fetch the affiliate identifier and package id from the localstorage and send to the backend to do the rest of the jobs.
I don't know if this is a good way of doing this or does it have cheating issue by users?
I am also considering adding the sales product listing to be part of the booking application.
Here is a link that points to the booking page when a button is clicked:

```
const handleClick = ()=>{
  window.location.href = 'https://bookingfrontend/live/6488e2f3a516ab0cdae740dc-experience'
}
```

Comment: So you set the querystring or unique part of the path. Not sure what is difficult about it or what can be cheated. What is your exact issue?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond just adding a query-parameter? Why not just `window.location.href = 'https://bookingfront.../etc/etc?affiliateId=<someAffiliateID>'`

Comment: I am even ashamed of my self. This is so easy. I just tried it and it is working. Thank you very much guys. Sometimes, we learn something new no matter how big or small it is. I am grateful for your replies. Thanks, thanks, thanks

Comment: @kingNodejs — Everybody's gotta learn sometime